# non-periodic orbit for compact subset invariant by the shift

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to solve the exercise 4.2.4 of the book of [Viana and Oliveira](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/foundations-of-ergodic-theory/F5AE11B50B16D9FF32909EA4BBA1E7CE), the statement follows:

**Exercise 4.2.4:** *Let $X$ be a finite set and $\Sigma = X^{\mathbb{N}}$. Prove that every infinite compact subset of $\Sigma$ invariant under the shift map $\sigma \colon \Sigma \to \Sigma$ contains some non-periodic point.*

There is a hint in the portuguese version of the book which is: Consider $K$ invariant compact set as above. We can take a sequence of periodic orbits $\{\mathcal{O}_n\}$ in $K$ such that the period goes to infinity as $n \to \infty$. Consider $Y \subset K$ the set of accumulation points of this sequence, show that $Y$ cannot be only one point. Then, one can take two periodic points $p \neq q$ in $Y$ and take $z$ a heteroclinic point, show that $z \in Y$ and conclude the exercise.

The unique step that I understand (actually, not very well) is that we can assume that $K$ contain some sequence of periodic points with periods going to infinity.

Comment: What is the topology on this seemingly discrete space? Or in other words, when is a subset of $\Sigma$ compact?

Comment: Product topology (generated by the elementary
cylinders).

Comment: I would search to confirm that compactness of the set gives that with only periodic points there is a maximal period in the set, which makes it finite. In the contraposition, if the set is infinite, there has to be a non-periodic point. This might not work out and you then need the more construtive approach given in the hint.